# Heroku Strapi Error: self signed certificate code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'

Tags: heroku, strapi

My application does not run in production. This is the code I am getting when reviewing the log.

```
2020-04-21T05:15:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-21T05:15:29.986534+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-21T05:15:29.986552+00:00 app[web.1]: > webzm@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-21T05:15:29.986553+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-21T05:15:29.986553+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-21T05:15:32.860504+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-21T05:15:32.860Z] error self signed certificate
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863444+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863445+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1492:34)
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863446+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863446+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:935:8)
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863446+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:693:12) {
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863447+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
2020-04-21T05:15:32.863448+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-04-21T05:15:32.876901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-04-21T05:15:32.877229+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-04-21T05:15:32.878225+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! webzm@0.1.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-04-21T05:15:32.878324+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-04-21T05:15:32.878522+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-04-21T05:15:32.878652+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the webzm@0.1.0 start script.
2020-04-21T05:15:32.878778+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following issue: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5696

An upstream package changed the way they validate self-signed certs that cause a failure.